# AJAX functionless

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have just built an AJAX function. Their are no errors with firebut and the correct response is returned but for some reason it will not fill the field value #crap of fill the div html #outdirections.

AJAX ::

```
function appdirections() {
    var start = $('#start').val();
    var end = $('#end').val();

    var dataString = 'start=' + start + '&end=' + end;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
             url: 'http://www.golfbrowser.com/courses/wentworth-east/?appdirections',
             data: dataString,
             beforeSend: function() {
                 },
                dataType:'json',
             success: function(data) {
     $('#outdirections').html(data.output);
     $('#crap').val(data.output);
},
      error: function(data) {
                 },
         });
}
```

PHP ::

```
<?php 

$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$end.'&sensor=false');


// data to fetch

$start = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/start_address");

$end = $xml->xpath("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/end_address");



// output

echo json_encode( array('output'=>$start));


?>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="crap" value=""/>

<div id="outdirections"></div>

<input id="start" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="enter your post code" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {appdirections();}"/>


<input id="end" type="text" value="wentworth virginia water" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Here is the response from Firebug

```
{"output":[{"0":"Winkfield, Windsor, Berkshire SL4 2ES, UK"}],"end":[{"0":"Wentworth, Surrey GU25 4, UK"}]}
```

Comment: did you try to see what's in data with doing console.debug(data.output); ?

Comment: Try first with some hardcoded text after success, check if it that harcoded data is updated to these fields.

Comment: The trailing comma in your object passed to `$.ajax` will fail in old versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you don't have anything in the `data.output`

Try this and see what it outputs

```
 $('#outdirections').html(data);
 $('#crap').val(data);
```

Im guessing #crap is an input field?

EDIT

anyways, try this `alert(data.output[0].get("0"))`

or if you simplified you could do this:

```
alert(data.output[0])
```

Comment: No it isnt that. I have updated the question with the response from Firebug

Comment: Ok, so you are getting an Object back which contains an array of Objects. Are you sure you don't want so simplify it by changing its structure to: `{"output":["Winkfield, Windsor, Berkshire SL4 2ES, UK"],"end":["Wentworth, Surrey GU25 4, UK"]}`?

Comment: Yes I do. That info comes from an XML Feed. I don't know why it is adding 0: to the output

Answer (score 0):

`<input id="#start" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {appdirections();}" />` implies this code only works for `event.keyCode == 13` condition.......This is enter key and an input element will not hold the value of enter key like a/b/c (I think so). For this, when you are pressing enter and calling `appdirections()` function `$('#start').val()` is null hence the code is not working...

Place the input fields inside a `<form>` tag and call the ajax function on submit.

---

Are you sure you are getting the data correct? Try to place an alert inside success and test if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the manual page for `SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
public array SimpleXMLElement::xpath ( string $path )
```

This method returns an array of values matched by the XPath query.  You are then encoding the array with `json_encode` and, surprise surprise, it turns it into a JSON array.

You have two options.  You can either get the element of the array with PHP or with Javascript. It's easier to do it with PHP, I think, and will save a few bytes!

```
echo json_encode( array('output'=>$start[0]));
```

Comment: That should have worked but it is still returning object Object on the alert